# What is the proper way to parse a Lucene Query in python?

Tags: python, lucene

I need to parse terms and operators from a lucene query in python.

The syntax is described here:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

For example, I'd like to get the terms and operators from a query like this:

```
title:"The Right Way" AND text:go
```

Are there any existing modules with parsers for lucene queries in python?

I could write a parser using ply or pyparse, but I'd like to know if one exists already or if there are alternative solutions.

Comment: http://metaoptimize.com/blog/2010/08/09/pylucene-3-0-in-60-seconds-tutorial-sample-code-for-the-3-0-api/

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for more of a pure python implementation. Pylucene depends on Java being installed. 

I use ElasticSearch for my search engine and communicate with it through http requests.

Comment: ElasticSearch should handle the query parsing for you, using a [query_string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/), or similar.

Comment: I do use a query_string query for search, but want to access the terms searched for in a query on the application side without necessarily executing a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) offers the [lucene parser](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/examples/lucene_grammar.py) in the examples folder.  pyparsing is written in pure Python without external dependencies. This seems to be the most solid implementation.